# NodeJs: Check if a file is locked without locking the file

Tags: node.js, windows

I am trying to check if a file has been locked with another application.

I figured than I can do that easily by opening the file in writing mode.

```
fs.open('myfile.docx', 'r+', (err) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log('File unlocked')
  }
})
```

However, I do not want to lock the file because the other app could write data at any moment.

So, is there any way to check if a file is locked without locking it (and without administrative rights by using either node.js or windows cmd) ?

Comment: I think here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690321/node-js-test-to-see-if-a-file-is-locked-for-editing-by-another-process#37707620

Comment: @lependu thanks, unfortunately, in the answer he locks the file. We are trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) utility from Sysinternals.

It works by looping through all Windows processes and listing their open file handles. You may want to filter the output:

```
handle.exe | findstr myfile.docx
```

You can invoke this from node using [child_process.exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

Comment: Thank you for this solution, but handle seams to need administrative rights and my app has only user rights.